# Find max overlap in list of lists

Tags: python, algorithm, list, overlap

I have two lists of lists:

```
a = [[0, 1, 5], [2], [3], [4], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12], [13], [14], [15]]
b = [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4], [5], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12], [13, 14], [15]]
```

How can I find the maximum overlap between the values of the lists and build a new list of lists with this maximum overlap.
In other words, I'm looking for a function `f` which maximizes the list sizes by merging lists with overlap.

The desired result of function `f` for this example would be:

```
f(a,b) = [[0, 1, 5], [2, 3], [4], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12], [13, 14], [15]]
```

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Say `a` contains `[1,2],[3,4]` and `b` contains `[2,3]` should the result contain `[1,2,3,4]`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Yep exactly

Comment: You can use a variant of *union-set* for this...

Comment: If the case mentioned by @WillemVanOnsem in comments is True, then why `[6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]` is not present as `[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]` in the desired output?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri Because the is no *bridge* (`[7, 8]`) I assume..

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: bacause there is no list that contains elements of the two lists. You only *unify* them if there is a list that has instances in both.

Comment: @Chris_Rands I'm wondering if there is already a function for this. Before implementing it on my own, I wanted to check that. But I have no idea how to search for that...

Comment: Are the two input lists guaranteed to each be overlap-free?

Comment: My feeling tells me that this problem might have *non-unique* solutions

Comment: @StefanPochmann It is guaranteed that there is not item in multiple lists within `a` or `b`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a variant of the [*disjoint-set structure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to solve this problem: for each list `[a,b,c]` you *unify* `a` with `b` and `a` with `c`. You do this for both lists and then derive the resulting roots.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42069677/67579) there is a simply *disjunct-set* algorithm we can modify:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def parent(u,mapping):
    if mapping[u] == u:
        return u
    mapping[u] = parent(mapping[u],mapping)
    return mapping[u]

def relation(array,mapping=None):
    if mapping is None:
        mapping = {}

    for e in array:
        if len(e) > 0:
            u = e[0]
            if u not in mapping:
                mapping[u] = u
            for v in e[1:]:
                if v not in mapping:
                    mapping[v] = v
                mapping[parent(u,mapping)] = parent(v,mapping)
    return mapping

def f(a,b):
    mapping = {}
    relation(a,mapping)
    relation(b,mapping)

    results = defaultdict(set)
    for u in mapping.keys():
        results[parent(u,mapping)].add(u)
    return [list(x) for x in results.values()]
```

(boldface added for the *semantical* differences with the original union-set algorithm).

This produces:

```
>>> f(a,b)
[[2, 3], [4], [0, 1, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12], [13, 14], [15]]
```

The result is not sorted, since we work with a set. Nevertheless, you can easily sort it on the first element of each tuple if you want by altering `f` to:

```
def f(a,b):
    mapping = {}
    relation(a,mapping)
    relation(b,mapping)

    results = defaultdict(set)
    for u in mapping.keys():
        results[parent(u,mapping)].add(u)
    return sorted([list(x) for x in results.values()],key=lambda t:t[0])
```

which produces:

```
>>> f(a,b)
[[0, 1, 5], [2, 3], [4], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12], [13, 14], [15]]
```

The nice thing with this solution is that it also works if there is *overlap* in `a` or `b` itself, and you can easily generalize the solution to work with an arbitrary amount of lists (for instance `a`, `b` and `c`).

Answer (score 0):

When I understood it right, the following will do it:

```
[l for l in a if not any(all(x in l2 for x in l) for l2 in b)] + 
[l for l in b if not any(all(x in l2 for x in l) for l2 in a)] + 
[l for l in a if l in b]
```

The first term yields all lists in `a` which are not part of lists in `b`; the second term yields all lists in `b` which are note part if lists in `a`; the third term yield all lists, which are both in `a` and `b`.

For your example this yields the following result:

```
[[0, 1, 5], [2, 3], [13, 14], [4], [6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11], [12], [15]]
```

Comment: This will not always generate the transitive closure I think. Say you have `a = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` and `b = [[2,3],[4,5]]` the result is `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [2, 3], [4, 5]]` whereas the expected result is `[[1,2,3,4,5,6]]`...